Dart macros error "The part-of directive must be the only directive in a part."
I'm trying to use an experimental feature from Dart called macros.
For now, there's a limited support from IDEs (The only way to show the augmented classes/methods is in VSCode) and it's required to use the Flutter beta channel.
What I've got so far:

A custom working Macro
An augmented class with the desired code

However, theres a problem with the imports section in the augmented file.
Custom macro
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:macros/macros.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

macro class ReviewableModule implements ClassDeclarationsMacro, ClassDefinitionMacro {

  const ReviewableModule();
  
  @override
  FutureOr<void> buildDeclarationsForClass(ClassDeclaration clazz, MemberDeclarationBuilder builder) async {
    builder.declareInType(DeclarationCode.fromParts([
      'external List<Bind> get binds;',
    ]));
  }
  
  @override
  FutureOr<void> buildDefinitionForClass(ClassDeclaration clazz, TypeDefinitionBuilder builder) async  {
    var bindsGetter = (await builder.methodsOf(clazz))
        .firstWhere((method) => method.identifier.name == 'binds');
    var bindsMethod = await builder.buildMethod(bindsGetter.identifier);
    bindsMethod.augment(FunctionBodyCode.fromParts([
      '{\n',
        'return [\n',
        '...augmented,\n',
        //<custom statements here>
        '];',
      '}',
    ]));
  }
}

The macro generates this code:
part of 'package:macros_test/home_module.dart';

import 'dart:core' as prefix0; // SHOWS ERROR
import 'package:flutter_modular/src/presenter/models/bind.dart' as prefix1; // SHOWS ERROR

augment class HomeModule {
  augment prefix0.List<prefix1.Bind> get binds {
return [
  ...augmented
];
}
}

The analyzer shows me this error for both imports

The part-of directive must be the only directive in a part.
Try removing the other directives, or moving them to the library for which this is a part.dart(non_part_of_directive_in_part)

Anybody knows what's going on here?

you need to remove those imports

@pskink this is an "in memory" file, it's not editable.

i know it is a file generated by your custom macro, those "import ..." directives are generated by you too i suppose?

No, that's the point.. These "import" statements are generated automatically. I have also tried a sample from Dart repository and this same problem is happening there too..

I have updated the question with the macro code...

but JsonCodable works ok? if so, try to get its sources and compare with your macro sources

Good tip... Tried here and got the same error..

I've just found something that can help.. JsonCodable has other experimental feature enabled: enhanced-parts. Trying to use it here

my generated code looks like: `augment library 'package:gist_foo/r.dart';
import 'dart:core' as prefix0;
augment class User {
external User.fromJson(prefix0.Map<prefix0.String, prefix0.Object?> json);
external prefix0.Map<prefix0.String, prefix0.Object?> toJson();
augment User.fromJson(prefix0.Map<prefix0.String, prefix0.Object?> json, )
: this.username = json[r'username'] as prefix0.String;
augment prefix0.Map<prefix0.String, prefix0.Object?> toJson() {
final json = <prefix0.String, prefix0.Object?>{};
json[r'username'] = this.username;
return json;
}
}`

what is your environment: sdk: ... part of your pubspec.yaml? also do you have `analyzer:
enable-experiment:

macros` in analysis_options.yaml?


environment: sdk: ^3.6.0-334.3.beta, analyzer: enable-experiment: - macros - enhanced-parts - augmentations

looks perfectly ok, when they announced macros i remember i had some weird problems in flutter code but when tried to run dart only environment it worked fine, can you try jsoncodable in pure dart code?

The main problem of "The part-of directive must be ..." message was solved with the enable-experiment: enhanced-parts. Now I realized that my macro has some issue, but that's something apart from this issue.. Thanks for your help!!

i see it, looks that dart 3.6 implements it in a different way: my dart version is still 3.5 and it does not generate part of '... code

To avoid the "The part-of directive must be the only directive in a part." error, the Flutter project have to include other experimental flag called enhanced-parts along with macros.
Found it in this PR from Dart repository.
The final analysis_options.yaml file should look like:
include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml

analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - macros
    - enhanced-parts

